# QGIS Lyon 2.12, select by location tool crash

Tags: clip, select-by-location, qgis-2.12

I'm trying to select points from a vector point layer (quite big ~2 million points), that are within a coastline polygon for the gulf of california. The area is in the south with quite a complex coastline.

I'm trying to remove the points that are over water into a new dataset.

Using the select by location tool (i.e. select points within land polygon and delete), QGIS crashes, I can only assume due to the complex nature of the coastline and the amount of points it has to iterate through.

I've tried using the clip tool, i.e. clip points using a polygon that represents only the ocean, again I left it running overnight and by morning it was less than a third done. (most of the points are over the water)

Are there other ways to solve this problem? Or is it best to leave the clip tool running for as long as it takes?

Comment: That is a lot of points :). I usually find that using the **Clip vectors by polygon** tool from GDAL/OGR can be faster. You can access this from the _Processing Toolbox_. If you installed QGIS using the OSGeo4W installer, you could run a clip function from the Shell command prompt program which can save a lot of CPU resources compared to running it inside QGIS.

Comment: @Joseph, great stuff, it was far quicker, 10 mins, rather than 9 hours of nothing. For anyone else processing toolbox > Vector > Clip points with polygons

Comment: Awesome buddy! Glad you found a much faster tool. You should post your comment as an answer. That way, you can close off your question by clicking the green faded tick (after 2 days of first posting your question).

Answer (score 1):

@joseph answered my question in the above comment.

For anyone else interested

For anyone else processing toolbox > Vector > Clip points with polygons

Reduced my processing time to ~20 mins from crashing and the spinning wheel of doom.